# LDAP compare username password?

Tags: java, ldap

I am new to LDAP and is using it with `com.sun.jndi.ldap` jar.

I have a login page where the user is entering the username and password. My job here is to validate the credentials with the data sitting in LDAP.

Till now I have connected to a LDAP server, authenticated and retrieved the uid.

Now I want to compare the password entered by the user and that in LDAP (password is private i.e. cannot view it when querying for the userid).

Is there any way to compare both of these passwords?

Comment: Hi Did you get the solution , actually even i am looking for the same apporach but did not find any thing in internet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. The correct approach with LDAP is to 'bind' to the directory using the user's credentials instead of your own. In JNDI this corresponds to the `LdapContext.reconnect()` operation, after setting the user's credentials into the context's environment as `Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL` and `Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS.` That causes the LDAP server to do the password comparison as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide me with some sample code. I am unable to use 'bind' with the user password.

Comment: Define 'unable'. I've already told you what API to use. What's the problem?

Comment: The bind operation can be a Login on some systems. The compare password functionality should be enough to check passwords and a username.

Comment: @musiKk The directory configuration may not allow access to other people's passwords. Mine is so configured. If you think there is a remote compare function that is intended for password verification you need to state what it is, and if you think that binding 'less correct' than using remote compare you need to state why.

Comment: @musiKk You said, and I quote, 'much less the correct one', and you are still mistaken. It *is* the correct one. Doing the bind is correct; fetching the password and comparing it yourself is not. For one thing, the latter requires reproducing the server's password hashing algorithm.

Comment: Does the password need to be encrypted before the binding or can it be set in plain text?

Answer (score 3):

We have several samples using binding as a user. You should mentioned by others, do a bind, never a compare of passwords. A compare of passwords is a poor practice and should not be utilized as some of the built in LDAP Server Implementation features such as Password Expiration and Intruder Detection may be bypassed when performing a Compare Request on the password attribute.

[JNDI Samples](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/JNDI%20Samples)

Answer (score 2):

Java LDAP APIs provide `search` operation which cause LDAP compare in turn. Here is [an example of the same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/search/compare.html).

Answer (score 0):

If there's an option to use Spring Security in your application, this has a module that'll allow you to integrate authentication with LDAP.

[Documentation here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ldap.html)

Comment: Hey David,Thaks a lot for the quick reply, but I am successfully able to authenticate and retrieve information. Now I am looking for a method like ldap_compare [Its a php method], which can be used with Core Java and Jndi ldap lib

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compare a field (not limited to username and password), you can use the following **wrapper** over the `search` method:

```
public boolean compare(LdapContext ctx, String dn, String filter) {

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = null;

    try {
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(new String[0]);

        answer = ctx.search(dn, filter, searchCtls);
        if (answer == null || !answer.hasMore()) {              
            return false;   // E.g.: wrong filter
        }
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        return false;       // E.g.: wrong DN
    }
    return true;
}
```

where `ctx` could be:

```
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(getEnvironment(userName, password), null);
```

and the `getEnvironment` method could be:

```
private Hashtable<String, Object> getEnvironment(String userName, String password) {
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, LDAP_HOST_389);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "DIGEST-MD5");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    return env;
}
```

If you call the `compare` method above, you will get:

- `false` if something went wrong (E.g.: invalid `dn`, invalid `filter`)
- `true` otherwise. In this case, if you inspect the `answer` in the `compare` method, you'll see:

  ```
  SearchResult sr = answer.next();
  sr.getName();                      // this is empty
  sr.getAttributes();                // No attributes
  ```

You can also take a look at the [LDAP Compare documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/compare.html).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correct, you are trying to compare the password entered by the user and the password in the LDAP in your Java Code. This is not possible in JAVA since there is no option for java to retrieve the password from the LDAP. We can only ask the LDAP to validate the user entered details. More over the password in LDAP will not be stored as Plain text, it will be encrypted and stored.

Comment: But there should be some way to verify my password with the one stored in LDAP (I will take care of the encrytion)

Comment: You can indeed receive the password, albeit in hashed form. Passwords are not encrypted in LDAP, they are hashed.

Comment: @Warlock, this is neither an LDAP nor Java issue. What I am going to say may not apply to your environment, but here it goes. Depending on the directory software and its configuration, attributes that store sensitive information such as user password may not be returned if the LDAP bind has not been established with a privileged principal/DN such as directory admin ID/DN (e.g., cn=root, cn=admin, what have you). It may not be a good idea to use directory admin privileges in an application if that application is not hosted in a protected and secure environment and [cont.]

Comment: it ensures the protection of the admin credentials. When you bind with user's principal (DN) and credential (password), the directory software already does the compare for you. If the compare results in false, then the 'authenticated' bind is not successful (you will receive an exception in your code). This tells you that the password sent by the user doesn't match the one stored in the server. Mismatch may also be caused by a revoked/nullified password; it depends on what the directory server does with the user password attribute [cont.]

Comment: (e.g., a password policy feature may be controlling binds and passwords). You should leave hashing/encryption to your directory server assuming you're using one that does that.

Comment: @EJP, LDAP doesn't define how passwords should be stored. Also, passwords can be encrypted in a directory. Hashing is more secure in certain environments (e.g., a directory server facing public network) because in case of a directory server security compromise, the passwords may not be recovered by the attacker easily (dictionary attacks are still possible though). However, certain directory server software allows passwords to be either hashed (e.g., SHA, SSHA, SHA-2, Salted SHA-2) or encrypted (e.g., AES).